# Nodejs OpenCV overlap image on face detection

Tags: node.js, opencv

This sounds simple, but it is really tricky.  I'm using NodeJS OpenCV to identify the X and Y of a face from a picture.

From the Examples:

```
cv.readImage("./files/mona.png", function(err, im){
  if (err) throw err;
  if (im.width() < 1 || im.height() < 1) throw new Error('Image has no size');

  im.detectObject("../data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml", {}, function(err, faces){
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++){
      var face = faces[i];
      im.ellipse(face.x + face.width / 2, face.y + face.height / 2, face.width / 2, face.height / 2);
    }

    im.save('./tmp/face-detection.png');
    console.log('Image saved to ./tmp/face-detection.png');
  });
});
```

I don't want to add an Ellipse to the image, I want to add an image ontop of the person's face.  How do I do this?

Using OpenCV, I tried creating a buffer matrix and merging the data from the 2 pictures.  It is really complicated.  I'm now looking into Node Canvas, but I would have thought OpenCV would provide a simple solution for this.  Anyone have some sample code that does it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the function **copyTo()** that is currently available in node-opencv, simply indicates as argument the destination image and the ROI (Region of interest) where you want to apply the second image.

```
NAN_METHOD(Matrix::CopyTo) {
Nan::HandleScope scope;

Matrix * self = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Matrix>(info.This());
int width = self->mat.size().width;
int height = self->mat.size().height;

// param 0 - destination image:
Matrix *dest = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Matrix>(info[0]->ToObject());
// param 1 - x coord of the destination
int x = info[1]->IntegerValue();
// param 2 - y coord of the destination
int y = info[2]->IntegerValue();

cv::Mat dstROI = cv::Mat(dest->mat, cv::Rect(x, y, width, height));
self->mat.copyTo(dstROI);

return;}
```

I strongly recommend you to take a look at the source code because this library is not documented.

It should work

```
overlapImage.copyTo(sourceImage, x, y, width, height);
```